# Google oAuth2 tokens invalidated more and more

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I have a web app built on oAuth2 that has been in production for 5+ years.  Users Authenticate and Authorize with Google and grant my application access to the Google Analytics data.

All of a sudden I am seeing a surge in failures when refreshing my users oAuth2 tokens.  This is the call:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Passing these parameters:
client_id=xxyyzz
client_secret=xxyyzz
grant_type=refresh_token
refresh_token=xxyyzz

This seems to be be on accounts that are less active (i.e. it could be 15+ days between instances where we make calls on their behalf).  I have to reach out to them and have them "ReAuthorize" against Google to get things working.

1) Did something recently change with Google oAuth2 or the GA Core Reporting API?

2) If access tokens are not refreshed after some time period will my refresh token become invalid?  i.e. should I make calls against all accounts even thought I don't need the data; just to keep the refresh token from going stale?

Thanks,
Mark.

**Update on Scope**
It was requested to provide the scopes in play here:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

Comment: Refresh tokens that are not used for six months will expire.   Going to see if I can find someone at google to ping see if this has changed.

Comment: Thanks.....   But I am seeing cases where it is not nearly this long.  In most cases 15-30 days.

Comment: I have seen a bunch of questions with the same problem over the last few weeks. I am thinking Google did a stealth change.   I am trying to find someone in my network with contact in their network to someone at Google Oauth. Might take a bit I have sent out a few mails.

Comment: BTW: This is an Oauth issue not a Analytics API issue.

Comment: Thanks....  this is reassuring that others are having same issue.  This had been rock solid for years...  now all of a sudden tokens are becoming invalidated.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: 1. what scopes are you using to authenticate your users?  2. has the user changed their password?

Comment: @DaImTo  Provide an update.  As far as if they user changed their password, I would have to ask some of them.  You are talking about their Google password right?

Comment: Yup their Google password

Comment: I got a response from one user that had their token invalidated and they report they have not changed their password in quite some time.

Comment: We are seeing the exact same issue as you, system been solid for years and then all of a sudden more and more refresh tokens are suddenly being invalidated. In fact we almost use identical scopes to you.

Comment: @DavidDickson - David....  the problem is recurring for me...  Started around 4:00pm Eastern Time..  You losing tokens too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11/17/2016 Update:

We did find an issue that resulted in some tokens being purged. We are working on to make sure it doesn't happen again. Unfortunately there is no way to restore the tokens that were deleted and your users will have to reauthorize again.

---

11/11/2016 update:

We are actively investigating the issue. You should ask your users to re-authorize the application.

---

(from Google Identity/Auth team) We would like to investigate this a bit more to make sure our system is working as intended. Other than the token revocation (with certain scopes) on password change, we haven't changed the token revocation policy.

Would you please ping me via my G+ profile?

Comment: sorry for being obtuse...  I don't use G+ unfortunately.  But did try for a good amount of time setting up an account on it and figuring out how to send a message.  If I understand I should be able to go to your page (https://plus.google.com/+NaveenAgarwal) and click an icon to either share a post or start a hangout.  I am not seeing any of these icons.  Can you email me at mschenkel@embeddedanalytics.com ??

Comment: We are seeing the exact same issue with our system. No issue for years then all of a sudden more an more refresh_tokens being invalidated (even when users report they did not revoke access or change their password). Would be great if you could reach out to me to help trouble shoot this problem. I tried messaging you on G+ but could not. My email is david@compass.co Any help would be great.

Comment: @nvnagr - any update?  Each day more and more of these tokens are becoming invalidated.  Please help!

Comment: In email Google states the problem has been resolved.