# Error refreshing OAuth2 token for G Suite Admin SDK's Directory API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

In November 2016, our service ran into the issue described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523864/1010375) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521704/1010375) and we had to get our users to reauthorize our application.

Starting from `2018-02-05T04:55:56Z`, our service started getting these errors again:

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

or

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_grant",
    "error_description" : "Account has been deleted"
}
```

or

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_grant",
    "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

Between then and the time the previous issue was resolved, our service encountered no errors at all. Nothing has changed on our end.

Is this a repeat of the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

`Account has been deleted` means that the account that gave you the refresh token you are using is deleted.

*There is nothing you can do about this the user no longer exists stop using the refresh token*

`Token has been expired or revoked.` means that the refresh token you are using is no longer working there can be several reasons for this the last being the user that granted you access has revoked the access via their google account.

*You should re-prompt the user to authenticate your application again when this happens you need a new refresh token.*

These are technically different issues, and should be handled differently on your end there is nothing you can do to prevent these errors as they are related to the users account and your access to it.

Comment: For the two error responses with descriptions, I'm aware of what they're supposed to mean. However, we are getting hundreds of these and only from that date (our application has been running for years).